# Laravel Mix - prepend formatted comments to compiled css output

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel Mix to compile and minify my js and scss files for the Wordpress website.

When I run mix with 'npm run production', the comments from scss file are removed. The file is a child theme style definition, and so Wordpress expects template header in the child theme stylesheet. When I upload the minified style.css file (without the definition) I am getting the following warning:

> ERROR: Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet.

In addition, there is no way to select page templates, when creating/editing new pages.

Currently I am copy-pasting the template header from the scss file to the compiled css file. I would like to automate the process by prepending a not-modified theme header file to a compiled scss file.

I have tried solving it this way:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv()
    ]
}).js('assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/')
    .js('assets/js/custom.js', 'public/js/')
    .sass('assets/css/style.scss', './')
    .combine([
        'assets/css/template-header.css',
        './style.css'
    ], './style.css');
```

But `combine` method [minifies the output file by default](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/31648d1a77c212b01367008feac7f6070d60cfcf/docs/concatenation-and-minification.md), and there is no way to override it.

I am happy with the file minification and removing comments, except for that theme header comment, so killing minification altogether for scss processing is not really an option.

Is there a way to combine the files to achieve the result I described within Laravel Mix?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. It requires one extra node package and utilized `then` method of Laravel mix:

1. Install [concat-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-files) package with `npm install concat-files`
2. require it in the `webpack.mix.js` file with `const concat = require('concat-files');`
3. append `then` method to `mix` with an appropriate callback. In my case:

   ```
   mix.webpackConfig({
       plugins: [
           new Dotenv()
       ]
   }).js('assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/')
   .js('assets/js/custom.js', 'public/js/')
   .sass('assets/css/style.scss', './')
   .then(function () {
       concat([
           'assets/css/template-header.css',
           'style.css'
       ], 'style.css', function (err) {
           if (err) { throw err; }
           console.log('done');
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: note: for some reason, I am not able to properly format the code part in this post :/

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simpler way to retain the Wordpress theme comment block in Laravel Mix. "In SASS comments can start with `/*!` to avoid being stripped in compressed mode." — https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/comments

```
/*!
Theme Name: Twenty Twenty-One
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentyone/
Author: the WordPress team
*/
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the selected one as it does not require an additional package and modification of your mix config.